# Best practice for using variables to configure and create new Github repository instance in Terraform instead of updating-in-place

Tags: github, terraform, infrastructure, terraform-provider-github

I am trying to set up a standard Github repository template for my organization that uses Terraform to spin up new repos with the configured settings.

Every time I try to update the configuration file to create a new instance of the repository with a new name, instead it will try to update-in-place any repo that was already created using that file.

My question is what is the best practice for making my configuration file reusable with input variables like repo name? Should I make a module or is there some way of reusing that file otherwise?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform is a desired-state-configuration system, which means that your configuration should represent the full set of objects that should exist rather than an instruction to create a single object.

Therefore the typical way to add a new repository is to add a new `resource` block declaring that new repository, and *leave the existing ones unchanged*. Terraform will then see that there's a new resource not currently tracked in the state and will propose to create it.

If your repositories are configured in some systematic way that you can describe using a mechanical rule rather than manual configuration then you can potentially use [the `for_each` meta-argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) to declare multiple resource instances from the same resource block, using Terraform language expressions to describe the systematic rule.

For example, you could create a local value with a higher-level data structure that describes what should be different between your repositories and then use that data structure with `for_each` on a single `resource` block:

```
locals {
  repositories = tomap({
    example_1 = {
      description = "First example repository"
    }
    example_2 = {
      description = "Second example repository"
    }
  })
}

resource "github_repository" "all" {
  for_each = local.repositories

  name        = each.key
  description = each.value.description
  private     = true
}
```

For simplicity in this example I've only made the name and description variable between the instances, but you can add whatever extra attributes you need for each of the elements of `local.repositories` and then access them via `each.value` inside the `resource` block.

The `private` argument above illustrates how this approach can avoid the need to re-state argument values that will be the same for each declared repository, and have your `local.repositories` data structure focus only on the minimum attributes needed to describe the variations you need for your local policies around GitHub repositories.

A `resource` block with `for_each` set appears as a map of objects when used in expressions elsewhere, using the same keys as in the map given in `for_each`. Therefore if you need to access the repository ids, or any other attribute of the systematically-declared objects, you can write Terraform expressions that work with maps. For example, if you want to output all of the repository ids as a map of strings:

```
output "repository_ids" {
  value = tomap({
    for k, r in github_repository.all : k => r.repo_id
  })
}
```